# Access Denied Error - CreateFileMApping

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7, memory-mapped-files

Hi all
I am getting GetLastError 5 (access Denied) for CreateFileMapping Function. Can any one help me please . my code as below

```
typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *NtSetInformationFileNext)(HANDLE FileHandle, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, PVOID FileInformation,
                                                  ULONG Length, FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass);
NtSetInformationFileNext Real_NtSetInformationFileData = NULL;
NtSetInformationFileNext Real_NtSetInformationFileVar ;

NTSTATUS WINAPI NtSetInformationFileCallback(HANDLE FileHandle, PIO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock, PVOID FileInformation,
                                                  ULONG Length, FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS FileInformationClass)
{

if(FileInformationClass == 10)
{

    FILE_RENAME_INFORMATION *pInfo = (PFILE_RENAME_INFORMATION)FileInformation;

            GetFileNameFromHandle(FileHandle);

    MessageBoxW(NULL, pInfo->FileName, L"Renamed To", MB_OK);   
}

return Real_NtSetInformationFileData(FileHandle, IoStatusBlock, FileInformation, Length, FileInformationClass);
}
```

In the above NtSetInformationFile CallBack Function i am calling GetFileNameFromHandle() function by passing FileHandle From NtSetInformationFile function , so inside GetFileNameFromHandle Function i am Calling CreateFileMapping by using the same Handle .

please help me if anything wrong in the above Code.

Comment: Um, there is no call to `CreateFileMapping` anywhere in your code. This looks like some sort of patching function, which is inherently unsupported. (In particular, you're calling back into kernel which will overwrite internal state.)

Answer (score 0):

[Overwriting initial answer which should have been comments]

OK.  You probably have one of two problems:
1) If this code is executing in the context of a device driver, then it is likely executing as a system process with system permissions.  Was the file handle passed in coming from an application executing with the user's permissions?  That could explain access denied.

2) The file was opened without FILE_SHARE_READ and/or FILE_SHARE_WRITE.

Comment: All perfectly reasonable things to say, but this is not an answer to the question. It should really be a comment.

Comment: Okay Kent ...now i am going to place that NtSetInformationFile function Hooking part please go through it once again .